# Strange behaviour in pandas.groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I feel like this is very obvious mistake on my part, but for some reason, the solution is escaping me right now.

So, first, create the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
A = {'device': 1, 'component': 100, 'value': 10}
B = {'device': 1, 'component': 100, 'value': 20}
C = {'device': 1, 'component': 101, 'value': 20}
D = {'device': 2, 'component': 100, 'value': 30}
E = {'device': 2, 'component': 100, 'value': 31}
F = pd.DataFrame([A, B, C, D, E])
```

Now, I want to apply a method to unique groups of "device" and "component". For simplicity, assume I simply want to get the shape of the dataframe

```
def simple(df):
  print(df.shape)
```

Now, apply it to per grouping

```
F.groupby(['device', 'component']).apply(simple)
```

The output is

```
(2, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

Which is what you would expect, but let's change this now

```
A = {'device': 1, 'component': 100, 'value': 10}
B = {'device': 1, 'component': 100, 'value': 20}
C = {'device': 1, 'component': 100, 'value': 20}
F_new = pd.DataFrame([A, B, C])
F_new.groupby(['device', 'component']).apply(simple)
```

This gives

```
(3, 3)
(3, 3)
```

Why does it not give me (3, 3) **once and only once**?

Comment: You didn't notice the extra `(2, 3)` on your first test, how was that expected?

Comment: If you change the simple function to print(df) you will notice there is an extra there too.

Comment: Wow, indeed I knew I was having a major case of tunnel vision. Didn't even notice the duplicated line in my example!

Thanks for the duplicate link @jezrael , couldn't find it on my own! :)